# Handling order of names in languages like Chinese

Tags: ios, localization

In numerous places in my app, I have a name displayed (current user or other user). I have 3 fields for name: firstName, lastName and fullName. Full is simply firstName + lastName, and not used very often. I use 'firstName lastName' more often than fullName.

I recently localized the app into other languages, among them Chinese and Japanese, in which the order for names is reversed to 'lastName firstName'.

I am unsure how to handle this change now in my app. Has anyone encountered a similar challenge and how did you handle it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this by saving a string called fullName in my Localizable Strings file as follows:

"fullName" = "%1$@ %2$@";

Then, in the languages that have the name order different, their "fullName" string is like this:

"fullName" = "%2$@ %1$@";

Hope this is helpful to someone else! :)

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that assumes all the names are in Chinese. If you have a mix of English and Chinese names, it's a very wrong way to display names.

Comment: That's true, although after examining a sample of the names we have in Japanese / Chinese, it made sense to do it this way consistently.